# MySQL - How to count word occurrences in article titles

Tags: mysql, count, find-occurrences

I´d like your help to count word occurrences in titles for each 'id' in a MySql table.

The table Article and ExpectedResult are available in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f985f/1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: . . Do you have a list of words you are looking for?  Are you just trying to calculate the number of words in the title?  As a general rule, including sample data and desired results makes a question much better.

Comment: as i understand and according to his expected result, he wants each word and how many times they used in title. btw, im waiting answer for this question, it seems cool

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

```
select a.id, 
       w.word, 
       (LENGTH(a.title) - LENGTH(REPLACE(a.title, w.word, ''))) / LENGTH(w.word) `count`
from Articles a join
(select distinct substring_index(substring_index(title,' ',n),' ',-1) word
 from Articles
 cross join 
 (select 1 n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
  select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
  select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12) n
) w on concat(' ',a.title,' ') like concat('% ',w.word,' %')
```

Note that the number of values in n should be the maximum number of words that can appear in a single record's `title` - I have used 12 here, as it is more than the largest number of words in any record's title in the supplied data, but a larger set of numbers may be required (depending on the actual data).

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f985f/19).